# When to use the lock thread in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization, thread-safety

I have a server which handles multiple incoming socket connections and creates 2 different threads which store the data in XML format.

I was using the `lock` statement for thread safety almost in every event handler called asyncronously and in the 2 threads in different parts of code.  Sadly using this approach my application significantly slows down.

I tried to not use `lock` at all and the server is very fast in execution, even the file storage seems to boost; but the program crashes for reasons I don't understand after 30sec - 1min. of work.

So. I thought that the best way is to use less locks or to use it only there where's strictly necessary.  As such, I have 2 questions:

1. Is the lock needed when I write to the public accessed variables (C# lists) only or even when I read from them ?
2. Is the lock needed only in the asyncronous threads created by the socket handler or in other places too ?

Someone could give me some practical guidelines, about how to operate. I'll not post the whole code this time. It hasn't sense to post about 2500 lines of code.

Comment: Not specific enough, look here for general info: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: There is whole range of possible programs - from absolutely wrong/blazingly fast to always correct/reasonably slow. You seem to hit both ends in your experiments. Threading safety is non-trivial topic, so I'd recommend reading on it instead of just trying to get "practical guidelines". I.e. eulerfx's link is good starting point.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is the lock needed when I write to the public accessed variables (C# lists) only or even when I read from them ?

Yes (even when you read).

> Is the lock needed only in the asyncronous threads created by the socket handler or in other places too ?

Yes.  Wherever code accesses a section of code which is shared, always lock.

---

This sounds like you may not be locking *individual* objects, but locking **one thing for all** lock situations.

If so put in smart *discrete* locks by creating individual unique objects which *relate and lock only* certain sections at a time, which don't interfere with other threads in other sections.

Here is an example:

```
// This class simulates the use of two different thread safe resources and how to lock them
// for thread safety but not block other threads getting different resources.
public class SmartLocking
{
    private string StrResource1 { get; set; }
    private string StrResource2 { get; set; }

    private object _Lock1 = new object();
    private object _Lock2 = new object();

    public void DoWorkOn1( string change )
    {
        lock (_Lock1)
        {
            _Resource1 = change;
        }
    }

    public void DoWorkOn2( string change2 )
    {
        lock (_Lock2)
        {
            _Resource2 = change2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey guy..You saved my life.. I used different locks (with different static objects) for different situations and now the app works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am amazed that this thread is locked! No pun intended. Improper usage of locks can lead to defacto race conditions which it appeared to me to be the case. I am glad my answer was able to help you.

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro: That's good, but you may now be trading one problem (bad performance) for another one (deadlocks). You can get into a situation where thread 1 has taken out lock A and is waiting for lock B, and thread 2 has taken out lock B and is waiting for lock A, and so of course they will both wait forever. As you add more fine-grained locking to your program **you must establish a strict ordering protocol for all locks**. You must say, for instance "I will never allow any thread to ask for lock 1 *after* it has already obtained lock 2". Your problems are just beginning; this is hard.

Comment: Yep a lock hierarchy does avoid this problem. But even without it: deadlocks are easy to debug - get the list of all locks currently held by the threads and for which locks they're waiting and voila you not only get the exact locks that caused the deadlock but also the stacktraces that lead up to it. Probably the best multithreaded bugs one can have in one application ;)

Comment: Adding the example from your blog **here** would make this answer better.

Answer (score 87):

You ever sit in your car or on the bus at a red light when there's no cross traffic? Big waste of time, right?  A lock is like a perfect traffic light. It is always green except when there is traffic in the intersection.

Your question is "I spend too much time in traffic waiting at red lights. Should I just run the red light? Or even better, should I remove the lights entirely and just let everyone drive through the intersection at highway speeds without any intersection controls?"

If you're having a performance problem with locks then removing locks is the *last* thing you should do. **You are waiting at that red light precisely because there is cross traffic in the intersection**. Locks are *extraordinarily fast* if they are not contended.

You can't eliminate the light without eliminating the cross traffic first.  The best solution is therefore to *eliminate the cross traffic*. If the lock is never contended then you'll never wait at it. Figure out why the cross traffic is spending so much time in the intersection; don't remove the light and hope there are no collisions. There will be.

If you can't do that, then *adding more finely-grained locks sometimes helps*. That is, maybe you have every road in town converging on the same intersection. Maybe you can split that up into two intersections, so that code can be moving through two different intersections at the same time.

Note that *making the cars faster* (getting a faster processor) or *making the roads shorter* (eliminating code path length) often makes the problem worse in multithreaded scenarios. Just as it does in real life; if the problem is gridlock then buying faster cars and driving them on shorter roads gets them to the traffic jam faster, but not out of it faster.

Comment: +1, I always enjoy these metaphor-type answers.  Makes things much easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It was pretty clear your answer but my intent was to ask: "if in real life people invented traffic circles how can I determine how big they should be to have better performance. So I was just expecting a more specific answer. Just "the circle should be about 100 times bigger than the ring of my wife" o something like that!

Answer (score 2):

Always use a lock when you access members (either read or write). If you are iterating over a collection, and from another thread you're removing items, things can go wrong quickly.

A suggestion is when you want to iterate a collection, copy all the items to a new collection and then iterate the copy. I.e.

```
var newcollection; // Initialize etc.
lock(mycollection)
{
  // Copy from mycollection to newcollection
}

foreach(var item in newcollection)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Likewise, only use the lock the moment you are actually writing to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you need to lock while reading is:

let's say you are making change to one property and it has being read twice while the thread is inbetween a lock. Once right before we made any change and another after, then we will have inconsistent results.

I hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Basically this can be answered pretty simple:

You need to lock all the things that are accessed by different threads. It actually doesnt really matter if its about reading or writing. If you are reading and another thread is overwriting the data at the same time the data read may get invalid and you possibly are performing invalid operations.