# Can i Implement Queue in this scenerio?

Tags: c#, windows

Good Day to all,

What I have to do is , I have to Monitor the Table Continuously,If the Table flag is true then i have to create a Text file according to the table values,  in  my local machine at specified Directory,I'm using `Timer` to Monitor the Table flag.
In this Scenario Can i Implement `queue` to write file or Directly can i write a file?

Edit/Update:
can i Implement like below?
The Table will be updated by different values with flag as true by every 30 seconds through another service, Here my timer will monitor the Table if the Flag is true ,it will read the values then add into queue. At finally I will update table flag as false.

My another function will monitor the queue ,if any values in queue, it will create a text file according to the queue values, if it is empty nothing to do.

Comment: Can you provide more information? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, or how you feel a queue would help.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, and it might help if the amount of data is very large, but it seems like overkill for small data. Also if there are very large amounts of data you have to be careful about the update back to the table  only updates the rows read in the first bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can i Implement like below?

Yes but keep in mind that the use of timers makes the program a defacto multi-threaded operation so one must be diligent in how the queue is accessed so operations do not access the queue at the same time and create race conditions.

There is nothing wrong with having a queue as an intermediate between different operations as you suggestion. But use a `lock` on the queue when, both, writing and dequeuing the queue operations occur. That way each operation can finish up without hampering the other.

---

In the class which houses the queue create a lock object which will provide a singular reference for the lock.

```
 private object syncObject = new Object();
```

Then wherever the queue is doing work, lock the object

```
 lock(syncObject)
 {
    myQueue.Enqueue(..);
 }

 ... in another method
 lock (syncObject)
 {
    myQueue.Peek(...);
    ...
    myQueue.Dequeue(...);
 }
```

---

See my answer on SO as to when to use `lock` in code for a more complete example, also the MSDN documentation on `lock`:

- [When to use the lock thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720778/285795)
- [lock Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Comment: how do i use Lock on queue? can u suggest some article to read ?

Comment: @OmegaMan, thanks I will come back with another question. ;)