# Reading text file into string array - why am I getting unexpected output?

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files

Trying to create a simple Hangman game whereby an external text (called words.txt) is read and strings therein are imported into an array of string called WordsArray.

Program compiles fine, however, it asks me twice to enter the file name before displaying the contents of the populated array (see foreach loop below)

Can someone identify why it's asking me for filename twice before displaying?

(Also, and more generally, is my refactoring appropriate for this simple application? )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string [] LoadWords()
        { 
            bool repeat = true;
            while (repeat)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of a file:");
                string filename = Console.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                    string[] WordsArray = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
                    if (WordsArray.Length == 0)
                        return null;
                    else
                        return WordsArray;
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException msg)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Check the file exists!");
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        static void DisplayWordsArray(string [] WordsArray)
        {
            foreach (string word in WordsArray)
                Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] WordsArray= new string[10];
            if (LoadWords() != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Loaded...\n\n");
                WordsArray = LoadWords();
                DisplayWordsArray(WordsArray);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `File.Exists( ... )` to determine if the file is viable, instead of catching an error when it is not.

Comment: It's asking for a file name twice because you're calling `LoadWords()` twice

Comment: I know that the call to LoadWords() appears in the selection statement, when its result is compared to null. However, in this case, i thought the returned result would only be called...not the full implementation therein.

Comment: Every time you call a method, the method code is executed. If you want to use the return value more than once, save it to a variable.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan according to Eric Lippert, the OP's design is correct - check out the "exogenous exceptions" section of this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @Rufus I've Met Eric Lippert back when I was an MVP. While I love his work too, I don't consider him to be, the be all end all, in what to do in design. For this I find it way more practical to not code for **known issues** by exceptions. Its neither right or wrong. See when I went head to head with Eric and was marked the answer. [When to use the lock thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720778/285795)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you call LoadWords() twice.

You should write:

```
string[] WordsArray= LoadWords();
if (WordsArray != null)
{
  Console.WriteLine("File Loaded...\n\n");
  DisplayWordsArray(WordsArray);
  ...
```

Comment: May i add another question? I've always had to initialise an array using the 'new' key word.  Why, in solution pasted above, is the 'new' keyword not used seeing that it is 'intialising' the WordsArray?  (Apart from the obvious fact that it is used a method's return value)

Comment: @Tiny - When you call `File.ReadAllLines`, the file is read into a `List<string>`.  Then the `ToArray` method is called on that list which initializes the array using the `new` keyword as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some comments and Jesper's answer, the duplicity is due to calling the function `LoadWords()` twice. It's a common cause of bugs and tends to arise from the need to write as few lines of code as possible (eliminating variable declaration and initialisation by using the function directly).

That aside, it is not prudent to deliberately trigger an exception when the error can be handled otherwise. See the following snippet from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions):

> For conditions that are likely to occur but might trigger an exception, consider handling them in a way that will avoid the exception.

Since a method `File.Exists()` exists to check the existence of a file, it is proper to use it rather than anticipate an exception.

**START_EDIT:** since files can be deleted, locked or otherwise changed by external processes, using the `try...catch` block is prudent as mentioned by @RufusL (check also Eric Lippert's post [here](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)). Mea culpa! **END_EDIT**

Finally, your refactoring is fine: it is almost always best to let a method handle one thing, and handle it well.

Comment: Fatal, bonehead, vexing, exogenous...haha! That was an interesting read @RufusL. I'll edit my answer lest some unwary soul falls into the trap.

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic to only answer the question once, and handle the known failure of missing file possibility. If an exception occurs, exit instead:

```
static string[] LoadWords()
{
    string[] WordsArray = null; 
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of a file:");

    do
    {
        try
        {  
            string filename = Console.ReadLine();

            if (File.Exists(filename))
                WordsArray = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine} File does not exist, try again: ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine} Unknown exception, exiting. {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }
     while (WordsArray == null)

    return WordsArray;
}
```